# Raspberry Pi - linux-headers directory missing

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

at the moment I'm trying to install a new driver for my PS3Eye to use it under my raspberry pi 1(The new driver is necessary for my use!). Following the [instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqljX.jpg) at http://kaswy.free.fr/?q=en/node/53 i realized that there is no linux-headers folder in /usr/src. I already tried `sudo apt-get install linux headers-4.4.14` - `Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.4.14'`; `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.14` - with the same error; `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` but the newest listed header was 3.6 version(Also did `sudo apt-get update` & upgrade & `sudo rpi-update` before) I have no clue how i could get the linux headers folder. I would be really greatful if someone of you could give me the right instructions to get this thing installed as my whole project relies on these.

Answer (score 0):

try using apt-cache search to find the headers you need. If you are on the newest version of raspbian you can use apt search .